# 500 OOPS: priv_sock_get_cmd

Tags: 14.04, 13.04, ftp, vsftpd

I'm rather new to Ubuntu and therefore `vsftp`.

I've setup the ftp server and I have several folders. When I connect, I can do so without any issues. However, if I try to access one particular folder that has jpegs stored within it, I get:

```
500 OOPS: priv_sock_get_cmd
failed to get directory listing.
```

I've added the `seccomp_sandbox=NO` option  to the end of [my config file](http://paste.ubuntu.com/13873487/) and restarted the service, but it didn't help.

I did delete the folder and recreated it - which worked for a short time and now I'm back in the same boat: I can't open that folder (get a directory listing)

Ubuntu Server version: 14.04.3 LTS, `vsftpd` version is 3.0.2

An `ls -al` of the directory `/media/ftpdata/sbp/09scandocs` gives a full list of the 100k files I have in there, all showing:

```
-rw------ 1 user1 user1 [file name]
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please give us a bit more information like: what version of Ubuntu you're running on the server and on the client? What is the output of `ls -al /path/to/directory`?  Please [edit] your question and add this information... Then leave a comment @Fabby.

Comment: Could you add the full path instead of the words "offending directory" and post  your `/etc/vsftpd.conf` to http://paste.ubuntu.com and provide the link back into your answer? (It looks like an ownership issue, but I need more info)

Comment: Thanks @fabby, I've included the exactly folder and here's the pastebin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/13873487/

Comment: Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/707926/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your questions in the future... **;-)**

Comment: I've just edited the answer!  There was an error in my chown statement.  Please re-read and then try again and then accept the answer!  **;-)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Easy-peasy:** You've got a mismatch in ownership: *the files should be owned by user root and group ftp:*

```
cd /media/
sudo chown --recursive root:ftp ftpdata
```

after performing the above and you want to copy files to/from `/media/ftproot`, just use `sudo cp`.

Alternatively, you could define a special ftp user and have that one own all files and run the daemon, or have multiple users each with their own directories, but [those would be new questions all by themselves!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)

Comment: The user that "puts" the files into that folder is called auser and are you saying that it should be ROOT instead?